# AngularJS reload data in page without refresh

Tags: angularjs, refresh, livereload

What i am doing is; i get the data from db and put it in

```
    $scope.GetMyData = function () {
        //http get request here
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.myData = result.data;
        });
    }
```

and when i want to refresh

> $scope.myData

I have a function which is ticking every 15 seconds to trigger my GetMyData function to get the updated data. The timer function is like;

```
$interval(function () {
                $scope.GetMyData();
}, 15000);
```

The problem is whenever I've overwritten $scope.myData, Page is not actually refreshing but the view looks like it's refreshed. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: after every call     $scope.GetMyData you get updated data, so page has no reason to refresh, the view looks like it's refreshed because you get new data. Could you explain your problem exactly?

Comment: @BartoszTermena ; It is somehow hard to explain but i'll try; I'm showing all user's data in page with ng-repeat, let's say there are 2 users in page and let one of the user's data changed. In the page for a second or less i am seeing 4 users (2 duplicated users). I guess DOM is not refreshing that fast.

Answer (score 0):

Use **$watch service** helps you to run some code when some value attached to the $scope has changed.

```
$scope.myData = "";

$scope.$watch('myData', function() {
  /*Here you can bind changed value to your view, updated value can be reflected on $scope.myData change */
        alert('myData has changed!');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not what I'm looking for.